# how to find records from another table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, rails-activerecord

**I have welcome,user,college,education model..
On the welcome page i want to show messages posted by only those users who have gone to the same college as the current user...but i am not able to show that. i have written following code in my welcome controller :**

```
def index
  @welcome = Welcome.all
  @newmessage = Welcome.new
  @college = User.find(@current_user.id).colleges
end
```

**using first line i am able to show messages posted by all users inside my view but that is not what i want.Using third line i am able to find current users college data but i am not sure how can i use this data...**

***how can i search only those users having tha same college as current users...***

**Following is the model codes :**

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :welcomes
    has_many :educations
    has_many :colleges, :through => :educations 
end

class College < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :educations
    has_many :users, :through => :educations
end

class Welcome < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**Following is my schema code for these models :**

```
create_table "welcomes", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "message"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                                 :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :limit => 128, :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                         :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.integer  "role_id"
    t.string   "ancestry"
  end
create_table "educations", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "college_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "year"
    t.text     "concentration"
    t.string   "attended_for"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "month"
    t.boolean  "private",         :default => false
    t.boolean  "approved",        :default => false
    t.integer  "approved_by"
    t.boolean  "alumni",          :default => false
    t.boolean  "is_mentor",       :default => false
    t.boolean  "approved_mentor", :default => false
  end

create_table "colleges", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "approved",   :default => false
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps -

```
User.find(@current_user.id).colleges.joins(:users => :welcomes).select('welcomes.message')
```

Comment: Can you see the output of User.find(@current_user.id).colleges.joins(:user).select('user.email as email').pluck(:email)

Comment: sairam...i am getting following error..ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'user' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: extremely sorry - its users . User.find(@current_user.id).colleges.joins(:users).select('user.email as email').pluck(:email)

Comment: pluck was introduced in rails 3.2 or late rails 3.1 . i assumed you were using the latest rails. ignore pluck and loop through the returned array.

Comment: No need to loop , just use ".map(&:email)" instead of "pluck"